# How should the name of a series of books be formatted?

Tags: writing, typography, books, formatting

I know that you underline – or if you're typing, you put the words in *italics* – the titles of books, and that you put chapters or quotations from a book in "quotes," but do you do anything to the font of a series of books; for example, Ranger's Apprentice?

I'm using this in an author's note, writing about how I am writing a book while reading a series, and that I want to mention that a specific series that I was reading inspired me.

Comment: Are you using a style guide? If yes, please tell us which one. If no, you can do whatever you want with the formatting.

Comment: @Laurel I'm not using a style guide. I'm just wondering if there was a strict guideline just like there is to books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're not using a style guide you can do whatever you want in terms of formatting. Or you can follow a style guide.

I think the following recommendation from the [MLA website](https://style.mla.org/trilogy-titles/) is pretty logical:

> The question of how to style a trilogy or series of books or movies that has no official title is less clear. For example, would it be the Star Wars movies or the *Star Wars* movies? Your decision will depend on what makes sense for the particular body of work. *Star Wars* is the name of the first movie released in the series. Since the title is foundational, italicize the series name: *Star Wars* movies. If you are writing about the Nancy Drew books, style the series name roman, since "Nancy Drew" does not appear in the titles of the individual books. If you are discussing the Harry Potter books, you could style the series name either way—Harry Potter books or *Harry Potter* books—since the series is associated with the first title in the series (*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*) and also with the character's name.

Answer (score 4):

As others said above, if you're not following a style guide, use your own discretion. I wanted to add one more point of reference as well. According to Chicago style ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Manual_of_Style/Titles/Archive_2), [link](https://apvschicago.com/2011/04/titles-quote-marks-italics-underlining.html)), book series titles generally are not italicized, but there are two exceptions:

1. if the book series name is the same as the title of an individual
   book, or
2. if there is a separate title for the entire series as a whole (for example, *[His Dark Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/His_Dark_Materials)*).